# Android studio 1.x AVD not running?

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, emulation, android-virtual-device

I'm a newbie android developer ,since i upgraded to Andoid Studio 1.x from beta ,things became a lot easy , creating the AVD and managing SDK is managed better by the IDE now ,

I used the Default Nexus 5 config to setup an AVD,however can you please tell me how to safely turn it off ,I cant find any poweroff button , i have Intel HAXM set up and working fine, I got an error saying AVD instance aldready running etc asking me to delete the avd from user/android/avd/... which i did ,

WHen i created it i can run it just once, when i close and reopen studio and try to run again i get the following message

```
AVD Nexus_5_API_21 is already running.
If that is not the case, delete the files at
   C:\Users\S****\.android\avd/Nexus_5_API_21.avd/*.lock
and try again
```

And what system image to use for the AVD, whats the difference between the ARM ,ATOM 86,ATOM 64 and googdle API images for the same android version, i use a windows 8.1 PC 64Bit running on a vt-x suported intel core i5 , 4200 u processor , which image should i use ,

Please Note i couldnt find solutons elsewhere and i doubt its an offtopic question as its about setting up a programming tool.
Btw the task manager shows a 32 bit emulator running
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here you Are :

[image]

when you click on turn on/off button emulator will be start/finish , also Remember after start emulator for first time you don't need to reOpen it!

Comment: Thing is i don't get this skin anymore using the prebuilt AVD_templates in android studio 1.x

Comment: actually this is happened when you run your app,add sdk and avd manager to your IDE,and i'm sure it's will be work :-)

Comment: i'm using Eclipse,and i was hopeful to make it better

Answer (score 1):

Delete all files and directories with extetion ***.Lock*** at ***C:\Users\user_name.android\avd\emulator_name.avd\files.Lock*** and try Again.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Tools**>>**Android**>>**Enable ADB Integration** select this, It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

make sure sdk and avd manager added to your IDE correctly.
answer of your second question is,when you play your app in IDE a emulator will be run and on emulator toolbox you can turn off or turn on your emulator and  also you can see your app running or not

Comment: How to turn on or off the emulator ,show with some screenshots etc please

Answer (score 0):

I meet this situation today, but the file *.lock was deleted (not by me) when i run this emulater failed with error tips like

AVD Nexus_5_API_21 is already running.
If that is not the case, delete the files at
   C:\Users\S****.android\avd/Nexus_5_API_21.avd/*.lock

so in the end, i duplicated this emulator and located the copy emulator's location and find the .*lock file and then i deleted it and it worked.